# Number of times data snapshot is received

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

```
mAuth.currentUser?.uid?.let {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(it).child("snaps")
        .addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener{
            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                emails.add(snapshot.child("from").value as String)
                snaps.add(snapshot)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
```

In the above code I get the snapshot from firebase database. I have 2 children under `snaps`.

My question is does `dataSnapshot` contain all the children as one or will I get 2 `dataSnapshot` where each snapshot represent one child?

In other words, `snaps` array list size is 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this code, `it` will be the UID of the currently signed in user.  The code will add a single listener to the child node called "snaps" under "users/{it}".

**The provided callback will not receive updates for any other child under "users".**  In other words, it will not see other users' snaps.  It doesn't matter how many users there are.

The callback will be invoked once for each existing child under the user's "snaps" child, then again for future changes to any child.

This is all behavior you can observe yourself by adding logging.

Comment: By mistake I typed users instead of snaps. Anyway my question is, consider there are 2 children under snaps then data snapshot contain both the children or there will be 2 data snapshots where each represents 1 child?

Comment: As I said in the answer: "The callback will be invoked once for each existing child under the user's "snaps" child, then again for future changes to any child."  and: "This is all behavior you can observe yourself by adding logging."